# How to prevent sidebar from disappearing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work with the template on this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/dashboard/

If you look at this section:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
```

You will find that when you reduce the width of the browser window, after a point the sidebar disappears.

The problem is that there will then be no way to click on the links in the sidebar. So how does one prevent the sidebar from disappearing, or atleast change it like the "navbar" on top of the page -> It disappears, but by clicking on the hamburger button, one can see the links.

Is there any class that I can use in bootstrap that does this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the code, you can see this:

```
/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}
```

This is essentially hiding the sidebar until you get to 768 pixels wide, where it then becomes fixed to the left. You can remove or overwrite the `display: none;` with your own code for mobile.

Comment: Any suggestion on how I can make it appear on top so it fits in mobile (stacked) ?

Comment: Currently when the `display: none;` is removed the sidebar sits above the content. Do you have an example?

Comment: If you click on the link in my question, then reduce the browser width you will notice that Home, Settings, Profile etc disappear and only reappear stacked when you click on the hamburger. I don't need the button - just appearing stacked would be enough. What would be the best way to do that ?

Comment: Is this what you mean by 'stacked'? https://imgur.com/c8PO67t (with the list items one per line down the page)

Comment: Yes! Thats what I mean by stacked.

Comment: It should automatically stack by default once you remove or overwrite the `display: none;` in your `dashboard.css` as above (if you have no overwriting CSS) :)

Comment: Can you tell me how you did it ? I have no additional css files except the bootstrap and popover files...

Comment: You may have some CSS overwriting somewhere. Are you using an external Bootstrap CSS as well as as your own custom CSS?

Comment: Im not using any external css except for the dashboard.css file...... The stylesheet I am using is:         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
I'm also using these scripts: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: And this script: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in in your `dashboard.css` **line number: 33**

```
.sidebar {
    display: none;
}
```

Just Remove it

Answer (score 1):

We can override sidebar disappearing by adding class "show" in bootstrapp 3

```
<nav class="sidebar show">
```

Or we can make collapse in bootstrapp 3:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-5 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">

   <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" >
      <i class="icon-paragraph-justify3"></i></a>
</div>

<nav class="sidebar collapse" id="sidebar">
```